# Package Java+Apache+MySQL for desktop use

Tags: java, installation

I need your guidance on creating java installation (may be exe) for desktop machine. Its web based application developed using JSP, java, Apache Tomcat, and MYSQL database. The installer will be packaged with - Web Server, war file, My SQL DB. When installer(.exe) is executed - it should configure web server, install my sql db and finally application icon will be created on the desktop. Clicking on the icon will open the app in the browser.

Is there a tool that can help me to accomplish this?

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html). They even have a wizard which can guide you step by step through the creation of your installation setup. Just try to use their "Java -> Tomcat Web Application" project wizard.